# React.js Unable to get property 'dispatch' of undefined or null reference

Tags: reactjs, redux

[Issue Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWj2Y.png)

I am facing **'dispatch' of undefined** issue when executing the application.

Whether I need to import any package to work with dispatch in React.js?

**ProgramManager.js:** This is my component this is where I am using dispatch to call action creator.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import {connect}  from 'react-redux'

import {postsActions,postsSelectors} from '../store/userList/index';    

class ProgramManager extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);              
      }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPosts({});
    }    
    fetchPosts(params) {
        this.context.store.dispatch(postsActions.fetchPosts(params));
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="right-container">
               ....
            </div>    
        )        } 
}

function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    debugger;
    return {
        //users: state.Users
        params: postsSelectors.getParams(state),
        posts: postsSelectors.getPosts(state),
    };
}

export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(ProgramManager);
```

**Store.js:** This is my Redux Root Store file.

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable';
//import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import rootEpic from './epics';

// const logger = createLogger({ collapsed: true });

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

export default createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(
            epicMiddleware,
            logger,
          //  routerMiddleware(hashHistory),
            thunk,
        )
    )
);
```

**epics.js** This is my root epic that combines all sub epic files

```js
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { values } from 'lodash';

import * as postsEpics from './userList/epic';

export default combineEpics(
  ...values(postsEpics)
);
```

**reducer.js** This is my root reducer that combines all sub reducers.

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';


import posts from './userList/reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  posts,
  routing: routerReducer,
});
```

**epic.js** This the sub epic file that actually gets data from the server.

```js
import { keyBy } from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
import querystring from 'querystring';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

import * as actionTypes from './actionType';
import * as postsActions from './actionCreator';
//import * as RequestModel  from './request.model';


export function fetchPosts(action$) {
    debugger;
    alert('fetchPosts');
    //RequestModel.entity = "sample";
    return action$.ofType(actionTypes.FETCH_COLLECTION)
        .map(action => action.payload)
        .switchMap(params => {
            return Observable.fromPromise(
                   axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/posts?${querystring.stringify(params)}`)
              //  axios.get('http://localhost:4040/admin/getTenantUsers')
            ).map(res => postsActions.fetchPostsSuccess(res.data, params));
        });
}
```

**actionCreation.js** this is where the disptacher called to get the state data from post

```js
import { keyBy } from 'lodash';
import * as actionTypes from './actionType';


export function fetchPosts(payload) {
    debugger;
    return { type: actionTypes.FETCH_COLLECTION, payload };
}


export function fetchPostsSuccess(posts, params) {
    debugger;
    const byId = keyBy(posts, (post) => post.id);
    return {type: actionTypes.FETCH_COLLECTION_SUCCESS, payload: {byId, params}};
  }
```

Comment: How can someone help you with out some minimal relevant code?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sagiv b.g I made some changes in the query please take a look?

Comment: @ksrider148 please provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: @ksrider148 please also provide your store implementation and how you pass it to context

Comment: Can't you just use `this.props.dispatch`?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a context object to dispatch an action.

I think the best way to have an action ready to be dispatched is by using `mapDispatchToProps` as the second argument of your `connect` wrapper, it will bring your action as a prop.

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import {connect}  from 'react-redux'

import {postsActions,postsSelectors} from '../store/userList/index';    

class ProgramManager extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts();
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="right-container">
               ....
            </div>    
        )        } 
}

function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    debugger;
    return {
        //users: state.Users
        params: postsSelectors.getParams(state),
        posts: postsSelectors.getPosts(state),
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps() {
     return postsActions
}    
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProgramManager);
```

`mapDispatchToProps` is usually a function that **simply returns a javascript object** with your action creators like:

```
{
    fetchPosts: postActions.fetchPosts,
    ...
}
```

That's why you can even go more direct (and no need to declare a mapDispatchToProps function):

```
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, postActions)(ProgramManager);
```

Comment: How this **this.props.fetchPosts();** in componentDidMount() will call my epic.js fetchPosts() method?

Comment: 1. The `connect` wrapper from `react-redux` does the magic. Connected components can both access the state (what you already did with `mapStateToProps`) AND dispatch actions (what can be done with a `mapDispatchToProps` function (or object). You can [read this](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact#implementing-container-components) part to better understand how the `connect` wrapper enhances your component to create a **connected component** (they call it a *container*).

Comment: 2. So the `componentDidMount()` will trigger the redux action. Now, if `redux-observable` is setup correctly, your fetchPostsEpic will listen to every action that passes in the reducer. If it detects the action `FETCH_POSTS`, it will run your epic code.

Comment: To debug or just check everything work, you need **chrome with [redux-devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/)** to check that the fetchPosts action got triggered. Then you can add a simple `console.log("I'm here")` at the beginning of your epic to check that your fetchStockEpic is well connected to your rootEpic.

Comment: Sorry, by convention, we name the action types and the action creators accordingly, i.e. `fetchPosts` and `FETCH_POSTS` but I see your action type is `FETCH_COLLECTION`. Just replace it above.

Answer (score 0):

React-Redux provides `dispatch` when you connect your components. So you don't have to use the `store` in the context to dispatch actions. You can simply do `this.props.dispatch(actionCreator())` within your connected components.

Note that it only provides `dispatch` to your component if you **do not pass your own `mapDispatchToProps`**. i.e., when you do

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
// or
connect()(Component)

// and not
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

If you provide `mapStateToProps`, however, you are expected to specify the action creators and wrap them around `dispatch`, so you don't need the `dispatch` for manual dispatches anymore.